# ACF editor form not rendering correctly

Tags: wordpress, editor, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I've added an ACF block to my Wordpress website using the `block.json` however it seems that when the user accesses the 'edit' view of the block in the block editor, the ACF form does not have any styling associated with it.

If the user chooses to 'preview' the block (forcing the editor form into the sidebar) the editor form somehow regains it's styling?

Has anyone seen this happen to their editor blocks before? It looks as tho, when the editor form is in the editor, it does not render any styling and I cannot see any styling in elements tab in the browser against it.

**When the block is in Editor view**
[image]

**When the block is 'preview view' (form in sidebar)**

[image]

My blocks are registered using `register_block_type()` that points towards file path for the `block.json` as described [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/create-your-first-acf-block/). The 'preview' styling for the ACF works as intended however like I have previously stated, the edit view strips all css from the forms

Comment: A comment for those who may have the same issue. I could NOT find a fix....I resorted to using the 'old way' of registering ACF block types